# jquery mobile select looks like plain html

Tags: jquery, select, html, mobile, append

I am appending a select input box via jquery mobile, however the output is just looking like a normal, plain, html select box.

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8jFG/)

Here's my JS

```
$('#admindiv').empty();
$('#admindiv').append('<select name="selectadmin" id="selectadmin"><option value="none">New Admin</option>');
for (var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
    $('#selectadmin').append('<option class="adminoption">'+i+'</option>');
}
$('#admindiv').append('</select>');
```

It should be in this format. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the jQuery Mobile code that customizes `select` elements runs at load time, probably before your new elements are created.

Following up with:

```
$('#admindiv select').selectmenu();
```

should do it.  It works in your Fiddle, at least with just the 1.3.0b1 framework enabled.